# Cascade deleting with EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I am having a few issues with EF Core at the moment. I have some data that I need to delete, and I am struggeling to see how the fluent API works, exactly in regards to the `.OnDelete()` function.

Considering the classic blog/post scenario from [microsofts own websites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete), I wonder what entity, exactly the `OnDelete()` is 'targeting' (for the lack of a better word) In some instances it seems to be the blog, in others, the post. Can the Cascade delete be defined from both sides (that the posts are deleted when the parent Blog is) if so i imagine the code should look like this:

`model.Entity<Post>().HasOne(p => p.Blog).WithMany(b => b.Posts).HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`

As i understand this is saying "When a Blog is deleted, first delete all posts referencing this blog" meaning the `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`applies to blog, not to post.

But is this the same then?

`model.Entity<Blog>().HasMany(b => b.Posts).WithOne(p => p.Blog).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`

or does `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` apply to Post rather than blog?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Cascade delete always works in one direction - from **principal entity** to **dependent entity**, i.e. deleting the principal entity deletes the dependent entities. And for one-to- many relationships the *one* side is always the *principal* and the *many* side is the *dependent*.

Looks like you are confused by the fluent configuration. Note that each relationship consists of two ends. The fluent configuration allows you to start with one of the ends and relate it to the other end, or vice versa, but still you are configuring (defining) a *single* relationship. So

```
Entity<A>().HasOne(a => a.B).WithMany(b => b.As)
```

is the same as

```
Entity<B>().HasMany(b => b.As).WithOne(a => a.B);
```

and they both define one and the same relationship. Which one you choose doesn't matter, just use single configuration per relationship in order to avoid discrepancies.

With that being said,

```
model.Entity<Post>().HasOne(p => p.Blog).WithMany(b => b.Posts)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

and

```
model.Entity<Blog>().HasMany(b => b.Posts).WithOne(p => p.Blog)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

is one and the same and define single *one-to-many* relationship from `Blog` to `Post`. Since `Blog` is the *one* side and `Post` is the *many* side, the `Blog` is the *principal entity* and the `Post` is the *dependent entity*, hence deleting a `Blog` will delete the related `Post`s.

**Reference:**

- [Relationships - Definition of terms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#definition-of-terms)
- [Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete)

Comment: Thank you very much for the VERY clear answer :)

I've just read that SQL Server only supports cascade delete from one FK on a Table. This means I can not really rely on Cascade delete, and still have to implement the deletion of certain related objects in my delete functions right?

Comment: I guess you mean the so called *multiple cascade paths*. Yes, SqlServer has such issue, and the rule is applied to EF (Core) models. It's possible to have multiple FK relationships with cascade delete as soon as they do not form a cycle. You should always try enforcing cascade delete, and if update database fails with multiple cascade paths exception, then you should break the cycle but turning cascade delete off for one or several relationships and handle deletion of the related data for them by hand.

Comment: Is there some resource that describes well when cascade delete "cycles"?

Comment: I can't recall. But I'll give you an example. Let say you have relationships A -> B -> D and A -> C -> D. When you delete A, it will delete related Bs and Cs. Related Ds can be deleted through A -> Bs or A -> Cs, hence you have cycle (or multiple cascade paths).

Comment: How to disable to default cascade delete (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#cascade-delete)?

Comment: @variable Here the question is *not* how to *disable* (which is elementary and explained in the docs you are linking to), but how to *use* cascade delete. And how it works - deleting who deletes the other(s).

Comment: If you can point me where the doc says how to prevent cascades delete then it will be very helpful.

Comment: @variable Here you go [Configuring cascading behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#configuring-cascading-behaviors)

Comment: Nice ok so this needs to be done on the fluent api code. My worry is that I'm using db first approach which has scaffolded the fluent api code and in future when I add new models in the code which I want to migrate into the db then I'm not sure what would be impact of fluent apis. Think this is what I will have to test.