# Problem removing item with foreign key in other table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I was trying to remove an product item, but I got this error message. I understand that I need to remove the foreign key in Stock table before I can remove the product from my Product table. I tried to set things up in my modelbuilder, but can't get it to work.. Is there any good solution to this?

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__Stock__ProductID__2E1BDC42". The conflict occurred in database "Inventory", table "dbo.Stock", column 'ProductID'.

This is my `InventoryContext`:

```
    public virtual DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Stock> Stock { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Storage> Storage { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Products>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.ProductId);

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Price).HasColumnType("decimal(18, 0)");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Stock>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.StockId).HasColumnName("StockID");
            entity.Property(e => e.ProductId).HasColumnName("ProductID");
            entity.Property(e => e.StorageId).HasColumnName("StorageID");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Product)
                .WithMany(p => p.Stock)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ProductId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__Stock__ProductID__2E1BDC42");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Storage)
                .WithMany(p => p.Stock)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.StorageId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__Stock__StorageID__2F10007B");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Storage>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.StorageId).HasColumnName("StorageID");
            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);
          });
       }
    }
}
```

And this is my method in the controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(long id)
{
        var products = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);

        _context.Products.Remove(products);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Comment: I think you need to have a look at [cascade delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete), is the foreign key nullable?Do you want to remove children (stocks) when the product is removed?Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Comment: Hi, I would like to remove the stocks when the products is removed.. I have tried cascade delete but can't get i to work..

Comment: Ok, that is what cascade delete..Do you configure it like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692144/cascade-deleting-with-ef-core

Comment: I have tried this way, but still the same problem...        
             modelBuilder.Entity<Stock>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Product)
            .WithMany(b => b.Stock)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);