# How to delete on cascade EF core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, webapi

I'm trying to delete the entities related to each other when I remove a row, but it isn't deleting the related entities. It is only deleting one entity and not the others.

My model

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set;}
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int CompanySize { get; set; }
    public string Branche { get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public Recruiter Recruiter { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

}

public class Recruiter
{
    public int RecruiterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int Compensation { get; set; }
    public string Education { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Hours { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasOne(post => post.Company)
        .WithMany(company => company.Posts)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    
    modelBuilder.SeedDatabase();
}
```

The call I make. So when I delete a post, I want that all the related entities are being deleted.

```
public Post DeclinePostRequest(int postId)
{
    var request = _dbContext.Posts.Where(post => post.PostId == postId).Include(post => post.Company).ThenInclude(company => company.Recruiter).FirstOrDefault();
    if(!request.Checked)
    {
        _dbContext.Posts.Remove(request);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return request;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692144/cascade-deleting-with-ef-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting the many side of a 1-to-many relationship there. Everything is working as expected.

Try deleting a `Company` instead.

Comment: Hmm, yes you are right. When I delete a company instead it is working. How can I make sure that when I delete a post, the others are deleted? Do I always need to delete the many to one relation instead of the one to many?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Imagine someone deleting a single post. You end up deleting **everything** for the company that post was associated with. Is that what you want?

Comment: Oh lol nevermind. Was a little bit confused. Thanks for the clarification