# EF-Core - cascade delete - The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Tags: entity-framework-core

When deleting a UserGroup the following exception is thrown.

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
> constraint "FK_SecurityAssignments_UserGroups_UserGroupId". The
> conflict occurred in database "AppDb", table
> "dbo.SecurityAssignments", column 'UserGroupId'. The statement has
> been terminated.

I've followed the approach from this post, but apparantly missed something ;-)

[Cascade deleting with EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692144/cascade-deleting-with-ef-core)

The models :

```
public class UserGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SecurityAssignment> SecurityAssignments { get; set; } = new List<SecurityAssignment>();
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SecurityAssignment> SecurityAssignments { get; set; } = new List<SecurityAssignment>();
}

public class SecurityAssignment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Customisation in OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    
    //Remove cascade delete unless explicit set below

var cascadeFKs = builder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetForeignKeys())
    .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
foreach (var fk in cascadeFKs)
{
    fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
        }

// explicit set cascade delete
// Remove security assignments when group deleted
builder.Entity<UserGroup>().HasMany(x => x.SecurityAssignments).WithOne(x => x.UserGroup).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserGroupId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

}

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code and configuration is correct. The problem was that I added the cascade-delete changes but did NOT created a migration.

!!! When changing the model by updating the OnModelCreated, DO NOT FORGET to create a migration !!!