# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : Entity Framework add record causes records to be deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a log table that I'm inserting into to capture insert, updates, etc. events during a block of code. The insert into the log table looks like this

```
public async Task CreateAuditLog(int reportId, string description)
{
    var auditLogEntry = new AuditLog { 
            dtCreated = DateTime.Now,
            iReportId = reportId,
            sDescription = description
    };

    await _context.CLS_Audit_Log.AddAsync(auditLogEntry);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

At the end of the block of code I have my last and final insert

```
// creates record in audit log table - email has been sent
await CreateAuditLog(newReport.Id, "Report Complete Email Sent");
```

Oddly enough when this occurs and the last `SaveChangesAsync()` is complete, my log is showing that its deleting records from 2 other tables, `Answers` and `Questions`.

When I check the SQL Server tables these records are in fact being deleted. This is confusing as I am not doing any deletes to these tables so I'm unsure as to why its deleting these records. Based on some digging I've done it might have to do with my relationships I have setup in the model classes but again I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The models of the tables that are being deleted from look like this

```
public class Questions
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string sQuestion { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Section")]
        public int SectionId { get; set; }
        public Sections Section { get; set; }
        public int IOrder { get; set; }
        [Precision(10, 1)]
        public decimal? Threshold { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("QuestionType")]
        public int IQuestionTypeId { get; set; }
        public QuestionTypes QuestionType { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SeverityLevel")]
        public int ISeverityLevelTypeId { get; set; }
        public SeverityLevels SeverityLevel { get; set; }
        public bool bHasSeverity { get; set; }
        public int? IWeight { get; set; }
        public string? sUpperLabel { get; set; }
        public string? sLowerLabel { get; set; }
}

public class Answers
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Questions")]
        public int IQuestionId { get; set; }
        public string? sAnswer { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Sections")]
        public int ISectionId { get; set; }
        public Sections Sections { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Report")]
        public int IReportId { get; set; }
        public string? sComment { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Files")]
        public int? IFileId { get; set; }
        public Files Files { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dtCorrectionDate { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProgressOptions")]
        public int? IProgressId { get; set; }
        public ProgressOptions ProgressOptions { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ResponsibleParties")]
        public int? IResponsiblePartyId { get; set; }
        public ResponsibleParties ResponsibleParties { get; set; }
        public int? IConstructionStatus { get; set; }
        public string? sAuditNote { get; set; }
        public string? sAuditionAction { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SeverityLevels")]
        public int? ISeverityLevelId { get; set; }
        public Reports Report { get; set; }
        public SeverityLevels SeverityLevels { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dtLastWarningSent { get; set; }
}

public class Reports
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ISubmittedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtReportStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtReportSubmitted { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtReportCompleted { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Location")]
        public string MasterLocationId { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public bool bEmailSent { get; set; }
        public int? IReportedScore { get; set; }
        public int? ITotalPossibleScore { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status")]
        public int IStatusId { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ReportTypes")]
        public int ReportTypeId { get; set; }
        public ReportTypes ReportTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the primary key, and what are the foreign keys, in your CLS_Audit_Log table. That appears to be the cause of the deletion from the information you presented, but it depends on the keys and relationships in your CLS_Audit_Log table.

Comment: [Does the link useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692824/7687666)

Comment: Something else is "touching" and removing those records via the `DbContext`.. You won't see it until the `DbContext.SaveChanges()` happens. This is one reason to use a unit of work pattern beyond the `DbContext` rather than having just the scoped `DbContext` instance with potentially multiple `SaveChanges()` calls scattered around. You likely have code intentionally or accidentally removing items from the `DbSet` or triggering a cascade delete in error but not actually saving the changes until your CreateAuditLog operation runs and calls `SaveChanges()`

Comment: @StevePy I don't have any cascade deletes defined in my code or in the database. I do have a few keys defined in my code. What is the best way to go about debugging this issue?

Comment: @TomRegan I have an Id property defined as my primary key and a reportId field defined as my foreign key in my Audit log table

Answer (score 0):

To debug this issue, the first thing you can try is to use a scoped DbContext inside the CreateAuditLog method. You can do this temporarily by new-ing up a DbContext inside the method, or injecting a DbContextFactory to provide a new DbContext instance. For methods like auditing or logging, I recommend using a separately scoped DbContext rather than a common injected one since we often want to write information in the event of problems and the single DbContext may be poisoned with invalid state that cannot be saved, or should not be saved.

```
public async Task CreateAuditLog(int reportId, string description)
{
    using (var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var auditLogEntry = new AuditLog { 
            dtCreated = DateTime.Now,
            iReportId = reportId,
            sDescription = description
        };

        await context.CLS_Audit_Log.AddAsync(auditLogEntry);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Doing this, there should be no deletion of questions or answers when writing the log.

However, the question is whether these deletions are pending in the _context change tracker. (poisoned) The first step is to verify what is in the change tracker for the DbContext at the point when you'd call the CreateAuditLog then add a line to inspect for any deletes in the main DbContext (_context):

```
var deletes = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    .Select(x => new { Type = x.Entity.GetType(), Original = x.OriginalValues.ToObject() })
    .ToList();
```

This should reveal the unexpected deletions if the DbContext has somehow picked up on a request along the way to remove these records.

It sounds like there is evidence in your logging that recorded the fact that these methods were deleted. A good point to investigate where the deletion might be happening is to search for the message fragment where the delete log would be added and set a breakpoint there to inspect the call stack. For example if the log message states something like "Question ID #24 was deleted by Admin", searching for "was deleted" should reveal the code that creates or calls a method to log that event/audit for any given entity. We can breakpoint that point and search any passed in arguments for mention of a Question or Answer, or use a conditional breakpoint, then scout up the call stack.

Another way to locate rogue deletes is search for any code that performs a Delete against the Question or Answer DbSet, or calls to set `.State = EntityState.Deleted` anywhere in the code, and set a breakpoint on these instances then run your test scenario. You will likely find that something in your code is getting hit unexpectedly and deleting the data. From the call stack you should be able to work out why it is getting called.