# Cascade / ClientCascade on Entity Framework Side (Not defined In Database)

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm unable to make changes to the database, it was reverse engineered into ef core models. I was trying to add the `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)` into the DbEntity model builder but I'm still getting the foreign key error "The DELETE statement conflicted with the fk reference". My goal is to automatically remove rows in other tables where the key is referenced as a fk if the parent is deleted.

Is what I'm trying to do possible or does the cascade constraint have to be defined in the SSMS side?

Modifying modelbuilder for child tables in dbcontext directly by adding `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)` unable to delete the referenced fields.

Here is my modelBuilder example. When I delete a sessionId from session, it should delete the child entity in S

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<S>(entity =>
        {

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Session)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.SessionId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Session");
        });
```

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692824/461444 ?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my code for the modelBuilder in my post. @AFract

Comment: Please put the real error and also how the database constraints actually look.